# How do I redirect the output of an awk printf to file?

Tags: bash, file, redirect, awk

In lines 104-106 in the following [script](https://github.com/brianbills21/scripts/blob/master/sample22.sh), if option `-o` is chosen: `./sample23.sh -o samples.bin`, the desired behavior is to redirect the output of the `printf` command to file. Here's the snippet in question:

```
    oPrint="3"
    if (oParamPassed && oPrint == 3) {
      printf("Total Samples in %s:\t%d\nTotal Samples Processed:\t%d\n", baseFileName, lines+1, last+1)
    }
```

Here's what I spent several hours trying:

1. In the awk portion of the script, I tried redirecting the output of the `printf` statement in many different ways consulting with many different articles. Nothing ever worked for me.
2. Redirecting the output of the entire awk script in bash at the end of `sample22.sh`, this caused the `-t` option to do the same thing as the `-o` option.
3. It is my belief that someone with years of awk experience will look at this and immediately see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the input [file](https://github.com/brianbills21/process-samples/blob/main/samples.bin) if you need it.

@tshiono's solution is brilliant, no having to change it even slightly. I did however put an up to the second date to prevent overwriting.

```
[[ $oParamPassed = "true" ]] && { exec > outfile-$(date +%m-%d-%Y.%H:%M:%S); }
```

And here's all I had to do in the `oParamPassed` if block:

```
    oPrint="3"
    if (oParamPassed && oPrint == 3) {
      printf outfile
    }
```

Output below:

```
./sample22.sh -o samples.bin

tail -9 outfile-08-29-2022.13:31:48

Sample 374364:  0x3403  0x0d03  0x4403  0x7803
Sample 374365:  0xee03  0x2c03  0x4503  0xf204
Sample 374366:  0x1a03  0xba03  0x4103  0x9c03
Sample 374367:  0x6103  0x3903  0x4703  0xf703
Sample 374368:  0x1603  0xf403  0x3403  0x7f03
Sample 374369:  0x7003  0x9903  0x3503  0x3503
Sample 374370:  0x1303  0x4b03  0x3703  0x8f03
Total Samples in samples.bin:   374371
Total Samples Processed:        374371
```

Comment: You only want it redirected if that option is given? And to stdout like normal if not?

Comment: Don't post links or images in questions, just text. Create and post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output, and your attempted **minimal** and **complete** code to do just the thing you're asking about so we can best help you.

Comment: `printf(...) >"file"` ?

Comment: I tried that @jhnc, but it didn't give the desired results.

Comment: If `echo|awk '{printf("%s\n","foo") > "file"}'` doesn't end up with text `foo` in a file called `file` then your awk is broken. Perhaps you should show exactly what code you tried and the results.

Comment: Put the code `[[ $oParamPassed = "true" ]] && { exec > outfile; }` just after parsing the
commandline options. Then just say `print` or `printf` w/o redirect in the awk block.

Comment: @jhnc `echo | awk '{printf("Total Samples in %s:\t%d\nTotal Samples Processed:\t%d\n", baseFileName, lines+1,     last+1) > "outfile.txt"}'` gives me the output of `syntax error near unexpected token (`

Comment: `syntax error near unexpected token` is a bash error. Are you sure you are using single quote characters? Some editors replace them with smart-quotes

Comment: @jhnc as soon as the OP provides a [mcve] we can help them. Right now, we'd just be guessing at what they want and the best way to implement it.

Comment: @thsiono, you get an a++, you solved the issue, your solution worked perfectly right out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shell to conditionally redirect standard output using normal file redirection syntax with an argument-less `exec` so the redirection persists for later commands. Minimal example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts "o:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        o) exec >"$OPTARG";; # Redirects stdout
        ?) echo "Invalid option"
           exit 1;;
    esac
done

awk 'BEGIN { print "foo" }'
```

Example usage:

```bash
$ bash demo.sh
foo
$ bash demo.sh -o out.txt
$ cat out.txt
foo
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot @Shawn, but I'm off to the gym. Thank you very much for your help.